# Huffman tree Codeword encoding

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-data, huffman-code

Problems printing out the binary codeword of the individual nodes inside this binary tree. I use an inOrder Traversal any advice on how i can generalize this? the tree looks like this 
[image]

```
    public static String Encodehelper (char[] s, BinaryNode<Data> root){

    Encode[] myCode = new Encode[s.length];

        if(root != null){
      if(root.getLeft()!=null)
        {
            code+="0";
        }

        getKey(s,root.getLeft());   
           if(root.getRight()!=null)
        {
            code+="1";
        }

         System.out.println(root.getElement().getSymbol() + " " + code);  

        if(root.getLeft()==null)
       {
            code=code.substring(0,code.length()-1);
        }
        getKey(s,root.getRight());

    }
    return " "; // for now...
}
```

returns

A 0

1

C 100

101

G 101

101

T 101

Instead of

A 0

1

10

C 100

G 101

T 11